# Reach out to Imgur

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Yesterday, I ran across a support-like issue for Imgur ([Imgur API removes audio from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580783/imgur-api-removes-audio-from-video)). The code was working, however the Imgur service was not doing the right thing (I'm no expert on their internals). Apparently, Imgur sends out the following email saying to post on the main site.

[image]

The first paragraph could be revised to help direct actual issues like the question above to their support channels.

I know Stack Overflow has a partnership/deal for image hosting, so official channels might work best.

Comment: So, you're suggesting adding an extra paragraph along the lines of _"If you have a bug report..."_?

Comment: @Cerbrus yea or _If you have a specific problem using the API (where the API returns a valid response)..._